# Como sobrescrever método "create" do devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Olá,

Preciso sobrescrever o método "create" do devise para fazer uma determinada de lógica antes de salvar o usuário. Porém não sei o caminho das pedras para efetuar tal alteração. Já pesquisei no google porém os exemplos não ficaram claros para mim.

Gerei os controllers para o modelo "User" criado pelo device através do comando `rails g devise:controllers users`. E pensei em sobrescrever o método "create" gerado nessa controller, e nesse ponto eu travei!

Por gentileza poderiam postar o caminho que devo seguir ?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Em seu `RegistrationsController` que estende de `Devise::RegistrationsController` a sobrescrita do `create` pode ser a seguinte:

```
def create
  super 
  #sua lógica
  resource.save
end
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.